# If variables are not in given range, return error message - but error message always returned?

Tags: python, sum

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why this easy program does not work. It always returns the error message.

It's a program that takes 5 integers and adds them up, however if they are above 100 or less than 0, it returns an error message.. except it always returns this no matter what numbers are put in.

I'm new, so I know it's perhaps over complicated or roundabout, but it should work anyways.[This is a picture of my programming.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgDxT.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures, post your actual code

Comment: Copy and paste the code here, don't make us retype everything from an image if we want to test it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or` doesn't work the way you think it does.

It compares the two statements next to it and if one of them is `True` then the statement is correct. In this case, *all integers* are true so with the first `or` statement:

```
int_one or int_two...
```

will always be true because integers are considered as `True`! Your comparison should thus be:

```
if int_one not in range or int_two not in range or int_three not in range or int_four not in range or int_five not in range:
```

---

To make this comparison faster, I would make a list and use `while` to make the user input their input into the list and compare them one by one:

```
user_input_list = []
i = 0

while len(user_input_list) < 5:
    user_input = int(input("Enter the " + str(i+1) + "th number:"))
    if 0 <= user_input <= 100:
        user_input_list.append(user_input)
        i += 1
    else:
        print("Please enter a number from 0 to 100")
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/Jo41/2)

Comment: Thank you. Separately wondering, how would you personally write that comparison to save some time?

Comment: @Lilac Give me a few moments

Comment: @Lilac See my edit. Remember to accept (the green checkmark) an answer if it was helpful in solving your problem!

Answer (score 0):

In the future post your code in your question using the code format options.

the "or" operator looks at the output of 2 expressions that return boolean true/false values. So the way you use it is incorrect.

```
>>> if 1 or 2 or 3 not in [1,2,3]:
...     print "hi"
...
hi
>>> if 1 not in [1,2,3] or 2 not in [1,2,3] or 3 not in [1,2,3]:
...     print "hi"
...
>>>
```

Consider the above examples. The first one is what you are doing. You should be doing the latter.